# java comparing properties of list elements , like list.contains(..) but by properties

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have two lists

```
class FirstElement {
       private int id;
       private String name;
}

class SecondElement {
       private int id;
       private String someString;
}

List<FirstElement> listF = getListOfSomeElements1();
List<SecondElement> listS = getListOfSomeElements2();
```

I need to find element in `listF<FirstElement>` if properties name=someString

If I need to find by corresponding of elements, i use for example:

```
if(listF.contains(listS.get(1))){...}
```

I use own method

```
boolean compareProperties(List<FirstElement> firstList, SecondElement secondElement){
 for(FirstElement firstElement:firstList){
        if (firstElement.getName().equals(secondElement.getSomestring)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

how to remove my method with Stream?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What parts are you struggling with? We will not simply "generate" the code for you. Please read [How much research effort is expected on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert your current method into a stream version then you can use `anyMatch`.

```
boolean exists = 
           listF.stream()
                .anyMatch(e -> e.getName().equals(secondElement.getSomestring));
```

If you want to find the first element that satisfies the provided criteria then you can do:

```
Optional<FirstElement> firstElement = 
         listF.stream()
              .filter(e -> e.getName().equals(secondElement.getSomestring))
              .findFirst();
```

There are various ways to unwrap an `Optional<T>` which can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the stream by the field that you need